# How to read multiple refcursor return by other procedure to another procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

i'm having one procedure which returns setof cursors
Now i have to call that procedure to another procedure and access the data 
that return by that procedure
is their any way to do this in postgres.
This is code for 1st procedure,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.returns_multiple_cursor( )
        RETURNS SETOF refcursor 
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100.0

    AS $function$

    DECLARE
        _daily refcursor := 'first_cur';
        _fac_hourly refcursor := 'second_cur';
    BEGIN

        open first_cur for  
        select * from x;
        return next first_cur;

        open second_cur for 
        select * from y;
        return  second_cur;

    END 
    $function$;
    ALTER FUNCTION public.returns_multiple_cursor();
```

Here code for other second procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.access_cursor( )
    RETURNS SETOF refcursor 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0

    AS $function$

    DECLARE

    BEGIN

    -- what code will be here to access the cursor data in this procedure

    select public.returns_multiple_cursor();

    END;
    ALTER FUNCTION public.access_cursor();
```

Comment: You can use [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html) in SQL context & its has a [similar variant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING) for plpgsql context too.

Comment: yes with fetch all it will be data from refcursor,but i have to use that data in my current calling procedure,Is their any datatype that will be do this

Comment: You can loop through the results with `FOR recordvar IN` (example in the [second link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP), at the bottom of the page). -- *The variable `recordvar` is automatically defined as type `record` and exists only inside the loop*

Comment: can you explain with code snipet, I'm not able figure out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the [`FOR <recordvar> IN <cursor>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP) loop, because it only works for bound cursors (which `refcursor`s are not).

But you can still loop through them, with the old-fashioned [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING):

```
declare
  rec record;
  cur refcursor;
begin
  for cur in select returns_multiple_cursor() loop
    loop
      fetch next from cur into rec;
      exit when not found;
      -- do whatever you want with the single rows here
    end loop;
    close cur;
  end loop;
end
```

Unfortunately, there is still another limitation: PostgreSQL caches the first cursor's plan (at least, it seems it does something like that), so you must use cursors, which uses the same column types (you'll have to use the same column names anyway, to be able to refer them in the inner loop, like `rec.col1`).

Complete, working example: http://rextester.com/FNWG91106 (see f.ex. what happens, when you remove casting from the cursors' queries).

If you have fix number of cursors (like in your example), but differently structured underlying queries, it might be easier to declare your `returns_multiple_cursor` as:

```
create or replace  function returns_multiple_cursor(out first_cur refcursor,
                                                    out second_cur refcursor)
    -- returns record (optional)
    language plpgsql
-- ...
```

This way, you could access your cursors more directly in the calling context.

**Update**: it seems that when you don't use explicit column names, just generic record processing (via f.ex. JSON or `hstore`), plan caching does not cause any trouble:

http://rextester.com/QHR6096

Comment: Thanks pozs for this answer.